# Unable to save NSUserDefaults values iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

I want to open a ViewController only once when the app start for the very first time. Below is my code. The problem is when I am writing YES to **NSUserdefaults** , doing a synchronise , and then closing the app. in Xcode using simulator , the value is not updated to Yes.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"isFirstLaunch"])
    {
        // app already launched
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO],@"isFirstLaunch", nil]];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
    }

    else
    {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES],@"isFirstLaunch", nil]];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
    }

    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
   if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"isFirstLaunch"])
   {
            NSLog(@"first time");
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    LASplashUserSettingViewController *splash = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"splash"];
    [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:splash animated:NO completion:nil];//
   }

}
```

[Why is NSUserDefaults not saving my values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2622754/why-is-nsuserdefaults-not-saving-my-values)

Have followed above and many other links. what am i missing here?
Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what am i missing here?

`-registerDefaults:` [doesn't do what you think it does](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9166770/643383). Use `-setBool:forKey:` instead.

`-registerDefaults:` is used to ensure that values exist for certain keys in the defaults system. There's no need to call `-synchronize` after that method because the values in the registration domain are never saved. You probably meant to use that method to set up the default value `YES` for `isFirstLaunch`, but your code checks the value for the key *before* you register the default value! which defeats the purpose of the method. Proper use would be to call `-registerDefaults:` first, and then check the value associated with the key, and if the value is `YES` then call `-setBool:forKey:` to save the value `NO`.

A simpler option to detect the first launch would be to invert the question. Skip the `-registerDefaults:` call altogether and change the key to `appHasRunPreviously`. If no value is stored for a given key, `-boolForKey:` will return `NO`. If that happens, you know that this is the first time the app is running, and you should save `YES` for that key using `-setBool:forKey:`.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you use NSUserDefaults in AppDelegate.m

```
+ (void)initialize 
{
    // Register defaults for first time
    NSMutableDictionary *defs = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [defs setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"isFirstLaunch"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:defs];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    if([defaults boolForKey:@"isFirstLaunch"])
    {
        // Do your stuff here

        [defaults setBool:NO forKey:@"isFirstLaunch"];
        [defaults synchronize];
    }
}
```

Don't set `isFirstLaunch` back to YES in the else-condition if you only want the view to be shown once.

Answer (score -2):

You can try this

```
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setBool:YES forKey:@"AlreadyLaunched"];


 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]boolForKey:@"AlreadyLaunched"]
```