# How does NSUserDefaults registerDefaults work?

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults

When i set registerDefaults in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` i set the default values for the NSUserDefaults throught the app.

```
NSMutableDictionary *defaultsDictionary = [@{@"userHasLoggedInOnce":@NO, @"firstTimeOpeningApp":@YES} mutableCopy];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:defaultsDict];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

How does registerDefaults store that it has set these values only once, since its called every time on app start? Is it an own value thats also set as a standardUserDefaults value? If so, is it possible to reset the default values?

Comment: @LordZsolt made changes so its not a duplicate

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4931270/1091539

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Register user defaults sets default values, for the keys. So when the application starts for the first time, you won't get nil, 0 or false and then have to test a lot of times through your code if that's the case. Instead you set something like "Welcome".

Edit: 
The contents of the registration domain are not written to disk; you need to call this method each time your application starts. You can place a plist file in the application's Resources directory and call registerDefaults: with the contents that you read in from that file. ([Source](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/registerDefaults:))

As the comment explained, calling registerUserDefaults doesn't override the savedValues, so you can safely call it each time the application launches. You can add a reset button, where you override the saved values by the user, with the values in your plist (defaults).

Comment: Registering defaults doesn't override any values that have been saved so it's always safe to call with a full set of default values.

Comment: IMO This answers the question more clearly than the referenced answer.